# How to change a button text using jquery in a if-else function

Tags: javascript, jquery

******Edit: Got it working: I had to change the id of the buttons to a class with the same name. I have no idea why this is-- if anyone else can answer that for me. Additionally, I have to use $('.an4') insead of $('#an4'). Again, no idea why that is.***

I'm trying to make a depression screening. After 8 questions are answered I want the text on the buttons to change. The button formats are all formatted like:

```
<input id="an1" type="button" value="Not at all" onclick='ph9q_but()'>
```

My code is as follows:

```
function ph9q_but() {
  if(ph9q_count > 7) {
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('.ph9q_display').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).text('If you checked off any problem on this questionnaire so far, how difficult have these problems made it for you to do your work, take care of things at home, or get along with other people?').fadeIn(500)});

      $('#an1').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).prop('value', 'Not difficult at all').fadeIn(500);
          });

      $('#an2').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).prop('value', 'Somewhat difficult').fadeIn(500);
          })
      $('.an3').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).prop('value', 'Very difficult').fadeIn(500);
          })
      $('#an4').prop('value', 'Save');
          })
```

The first action triggers properly, so the if statement is working, however I cannot find out a correct way to change the text of the buttons along with the "ph9q_display" variable that works. I've tried .text, .var, and .prop. I've tried getting rid of the fade in and out parts. None of them work. Out of ideas now.

Comment: `$('#selector').prop('value', 'something')` and `$('#selector').val('something')` both work for me

Comment: This is about the edit you've added. Did you by any chance have multiple HTML elements with the same id?

Comment: To 3limin4t0r: I did not, each of the buttons had their own unique ID